# How to update the input field when other input field is edited using React useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There are 3 numeric input fields: a, b and c.
When user edits "a" or "b" then "c" should be calculated as a*b.
When "c" is edited then look which  field was edited most recently:
   if "a" then "b" = c/a
   if "b" then "a" = c/b

The following working code allows to edit a, b and c.
I cannot figure out how to implement the calculation a  or b if c is edited.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Calc = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState( { a: 3, b: 2, c: 6 });
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="a">a</label>
        <input type="number" id="a" name="a" onChange={handleChange} value={values.a} />
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="b"> b </label>
        <input type="number" id="b" name="b" onChange={handleChange} value={values.b}  />
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="c"> c </label>
        <input type="number" id="c" name="c" onChange={handleChange} value={values.c}  />
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};
```

To make multiplication for calculating "c" I added to the end of handleChange()

```
 if (name === 'a') {
      setValues({ ...values, a: value, c: value * values.b });
 }
 if (name === 'b') {
      setValues({ ...values, b: value, c: value * values.a });
 }
```

but I do not know how to  calculate "a" or "b" when "c" is edited because I need to  decide which field "a"  or "b" needs to be calculated based on last edit event between these 2.

Comment: sorry don't understand your question.  Can you give some samples such as:
given {a:1, b:2, c:3} when set c = 5, then ....

Answer (score 1):

You should be create an internal state to handle `field was edited most recently` like this:

```
const [recentlyValue, setRecentlyValue] = useState("");
if (name === "a") {
    setRecentlyValue(name);
    setValues({ ...values, a: value, c: value * values.b });
}
if (name === "b") {
    setRecentlyValue(name);
    setValues({ ...values, b: value, c: value * values.a });
}
// check recentlyValue with case `c`
if (name === "c") {
    if (recentlyValue === "a") {
        // b = c/a
        setValues({ ...values, b: value / values.a, c: value });
    }
    if (recentlyValue === "b") {
        // a = c/b
        setValues({ ...values, a: value / values.b, c: value });
    }
    // Handle case not yet change a and b here, or don't do anything
}
```

[My Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-rhodes-f7grw)

Comment: Consider 3 diff functions changeA, changeB, changeC and avoid so many if and nesting.  Try to avoid long functions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing nesting if else condition in one funtion, I would suggest you to create three different functions and maintain the values update separately. In that way maintainence would be easy in long run. Check the below logic -

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState( { a: 3, b: 2, c: 6 });
  const [lastChangedValue, setLastChangedValue] = useState("");

  const handleChangeA = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({ ...values, a: value, c: value * values.b });
    setLastChangedValue(name);
  }
  const handleChangeB = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({ ...values, b: value, c: value * values.a });
    setLastChangedValue(name);
  }
  const handleChangeC = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (lastChangedValue === 'a') {
      setValues({ ...values, c: value, b: value / values.a });
    }
    if (lastChangedValue === 'b') {
      setValues({ ...values, c: value, a: value / values.b });
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="a">a</label>
        <input type="number" id="a" name="a" onChange={handleChangeA} value={values.a} />
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="b"> b </label>
        <input type="number" id="b" name="b" onChange={handleChangeB} value={values.b}  />
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="c"> c </label>
        <input type="number" id="c" name="c" onChange={handleChangeC} value={values.c}  />
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```